# Hyperledger Farbic v2.0 problem with ChaincodeException payload

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

The main problem is getting payload error from client perspective.

**Basic setup**:

Fabric chaincode -> implemented in Java with fabric-chaincode-shim: v2.3.0

Application client -> implemented in Typescript by using fabric-network: 2.2.5.

Every transaction which were implemented works properly but I would like to know how can I implement error_codes which should be readable by client.

When I was throwing ChaincodeException with payload as below, then I have got empty buffer property from client application perspective.

Example code from chaincode perspective:

```java
public void createAsset(final Context ctx, String createAssetDto) { 
    throw new ChaincodeException("Sample message", "SamplePayloadWithSpecifiedCode");
}
```

Example code from application client perspective:

```js
    try {
        await contract.submitTransaction('createAsset', JSON.stringify(createAssetDto));
        success = true;
    } catch (err) {
        logException(err);
        success = false;
    }
```

I have noticed that in peer implementation there is a function which parse ChaincodeMessage as an Error

```golang
    case pb.ChaincodeMessage_ERROR:
        return nil, resp.ChaincodeEvent, errors.Errorf("transaction returned with failure: %s", resp.Payload)
```

From peer perspective log:

```
failed to invoke chaincode ecmr, error: transaction returned with failure: Sample Message
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.processChaincodeExecutionResult
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:182
```

From this perspective it means that ChaincodeException message is the payload.

From client perspective error has got:

```js
{
  status: 500,
  message: "error in simulation: transaction returned with failure: Sample Message",
  payload: {
  },
}
```

I think that I should get "SamplePayloadWithSpecifiedCode" in response.payload property.

I've already found possible the place in source code where message is set as payload from ChaincodeException in java chaincode implementation:
[image]

Any advice welcome. Thanks

Comment: I think this issue has come up before, on the Hyperledger fabric-sdk-java rocket chat channel - https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-java?msg=ECygGAdLD6cd2HoYx
It might be worth opening an issue on jira - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/CONTRIBUTING.html#reporting-bugs

Comment: Simply conclusion - fabric java chaincode implementation returns improper payload (only message from ChaincodeException). Payload from ChaincodeException is omitted. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

SDKs should provide the payload in case of error in Fabric v2.x. however this is currently a known issue. You can check through Fabric Jira and Rocket Chat.

See the related links below.

1. [FABN-1667](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1667) - `Payload no longer provided in Evaluation errors in SDK`
2. [FABG-974](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABG-974) - `Error codes >= 400 do not return a message or payload`
3. [FABN-1041](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1041) - `inconsistent response if promise is rejected`
4. [Java SDK chat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-java/thread/ECygGAdLD6cd2HoYx?msg=ECygGAdLD6cd2HoYx)

- Returning contexts(with error logs) to the client(requester) can see the internal structure, it is considered bad security practice

Comment: Error payloads from chaincode should be provided by the SDKs so I think this is a bug rather than by design. You're absolutely right that chaincode implementations shouldn't leak sensitive information via errors though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there seems to be a problem with the expression. Maybe it's a translator problem. What I intended is an implementation, not a design. :(

Comment: In the case of edit, my function is currently blocked, so it will be modified after release.